# Django 4: settings.DEBUG not correct when running tests

Tags: django-4.0

I am trying to write a Django (4) test. It has to work differently depending on the DEBUG constant in my settings.py.
So I started with something like:

```
def my_test(self):
    from django.conf import settings

    if settings.DEBUG:
    ....
    else:
    ....
```

I noticed the code never executed the first part of the if so I added:

```
print(settings.DEBUG)
```

And I noticed this prints always False. Even if DEBUG is set to True in my settings.py.

I tried with some others constants there (INSTALLED_APPS, ALLOWED_HOSTS) and all of them return the correct value.

Why is that? How to access the real DEBUG constant in my settings.py?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding [--debug-mode](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/django-admin/#cmdoption-test-debug-mode) flag solved the issue:

> python manage.py test --debug-mode

```
--debug-mode

Sets the DEBUG setting to True prior to running tests. This may help troubleshoot test failures.
```